# Git pull while keeping original group of the updated files

Tags: git

**I have the following scenario:**

A developer makes changes on the development machine, and `git commit` to a central repository.  A group of people help update the web site.  I have made the entire source code owned by user1.git (i.e. a dedicated group for all administrators, user1, user2 etc) and writable by group members.

However I find that when user2 `git pull origin master`, the updated files are now owned by user2.user2, meaning user3 cannot update this file in the next `git pull`.  I do not want to make the source code writable by everyone, which should not be good practice.

How can I `git pull` and yet the new files are owned by user2.git (keeping the group git)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a git problem specifically but a permissions problem on files (the fact that it is a git directory is your use case for multiple users in a directory but it is applicable to others too).  The solution is to mark the directory as set group id.

If you have the directory `my_project` with the git repo in it (so `my_project/.git`) then run the commands: `chown root:git my_project` and `chmod g+s my_project` and then all files in that directory should have git as the group set.

Comment: Thanks dave.  This worked up to a point. The permissions of .git/index and ORIG_HEAD became group NOT writable after `git pull`, despite I had explicitly made them so.

Comment: The permissions on the .git directory might not be setgpid?

Comment: You meant setting sticky gid or setgpid (which I cannot find)?  The permission of .git directory is drwxrwsr-x whereas .git/index became -rw-r--r--

Comment: Everything works now. Don't know why.  Thank you Dave.